# Changing labels with logo images

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to build a graph with [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) and i would like to replace the labels with logtype small images.

Is it possible ? Can't find the way to do it.
Thanks.

This is my chart options:

```
var horizontalBarChartData3 = {
    labels: ["mark1", "mark2", "mark3", "mark4","mark5"],
    datasets: [
    {
        label: 'USA',
        backgroundColor: "rgba(196,196,196,0.5)",
        data: [0.07,0.02,0.26,0.68,0.21]
    }, 
    {
         hidden: false,
         label: 'EUROPA',
         backgroundColor: "rgba(125,125,125,0.5)",
         data: [0.09,0.02,0.31,0.74,0.23]
    }, 
    {
         label: 'CHINA',
         backgroundColor: "rgba(165,157,4,0.5)",
         data: [0.15,0.02,0.38,0.99,0.27]
    }]
};
```

Comment: Look this [answer](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3259), you can find some info

Answer (score 0):

Adding an image to the labels is a tricky adjustment, and will require fiddling with chart.js code, as it isn't natively supported. My best suggestion is to avoid attempts to add your images to the labels themselves.

Best solution for using icons would be one of:

1. Use images of your own, but place them around the chart in proper positions, and if needed, refer to em in labels.
2. Use an icon font to insert icons as characters of text. Here's an example using [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/), using your data (based off of [this](http://jsfiddle.net/JWp7W/5/) fiddle):

```js
var randomScalingFactor = function () {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
};

var barChartData = {
    pointLabelFontFamily: "'FontAwesome'",
    labels: ["\uf000", "\uf001", "\uf002", "\uf003", "\uf004"],
    datasets: [
{
    label: 'USA',
    backgroundColor: "rgba(196,196,196,0.5)",
    data: [0.07,0.02,0.26,0.68,0.21]
}, 
{
     hidden: false,
     label: 'EUROPA',
     backgroundColor: "rgba(125,125,125,0.5)",
     data: [0.09,0.02,0.31,0.74,0.23]
}, 
{
     label: 'CHINA',
     backgroundColor: "rgba(165,157,4,0.5)",
     data: [0.15,0.02,0.38,0.99,0.27]
}]

};

    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
        responsive: true,
        scaleFontFamily: "'FontAwesome'"
    });
```

```html
<script src="http://chartjs.org/assets/Chart.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div style="width: 75%">
    <span style="font-family: FontAwesome">&#xf015;</span>
    <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I 've made svg images representing flags. 
Beginner in js use , is it possible to add , my images as dontAwesome ?